# val x = { println("hello") } as inline function

Tags: scala

I execute the following assignment:-

```
val x = { println("hello") }
```

This prints hello and also prints the type of x as:-

```
x: Unit = ()
```

My understanding was that an inline function has been created and assigned to val x. So with that assumption I tried executing x as:-

```
x
```

It doesn't error out. But also prints nothing. Isn't that a function which x is holding?

Comment: Use `def` instead of `val`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning a function to x, you are assigning the result of a block to x. The block is executed immediately and the result (Unit) is assigned to x.

The result of a block is the result of the last statement in the block, and the result of println() is Unit.

```
val x = () => { println("hello") }
```

will assign a function to x, which can be called like this:

```
x()
```

Comment: `{ ... }` is a block, not an anonymous function. Also, there's no difference in Scala between function and anonymous function, because Scala has only anonymous functions and methods.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan What about `class LengthFunc extends (String => Int) { def apply(s: String) = s.length }` `val f = new LengthFunc `? would `f` be a named function? As opposed to `val f = (s: String) => s.length`, which is an anonymous function.

Comment: @dcastro that's a good point. Yeah, that's a named function. It never crossed my mind because I tend to see it more as a class than as a function, but it is, indeed, a function.

Comment: @dcastro actually, `object LengthFunc extends (String => Int)` would be a named function, i.e., `object` instead of `class`.

Answer (score 4):

What this line does:

```
val x = { println("hello") }
```

is this: it executes `println("hello")` and then assigns what `println` returns to the value `x`. Since `println` returns `Unit`, `x` will be assigned `Unit`.

The correct syntax for what you want to do (assign a function to `x`) is this:

```
val x = () => { println("hello") }
```

You can then call the function with:

```
x()
```

(which is short-hand syntax for `x.apply()`).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use `def` instead of `val`. `val` introduces constant values defined as the result of the block defining them. In your example, `println("hello")` is executed, then its returning value is named `x`. On the contrary, `def` introduces a method whose body is executed every time you call it.

```
def x = println("hello")
```

will then be executed every time `x` is called. But even with def, it's still not a function. To make it a function you have two options:

- you can define directly a function `(x1 : T1, ..., xn : Tn) => expr` where `x1` to `xn` are the arguments of the function, `Ti` is the type of `xi` and `expr` is the code you want to execute (which depends on parameters `x1` to `xn` and anything in scope).

  ```
  scala> val x = () => println("hello")
  x: () => Unit = <function0>
  ```
- or you can define a method as before and use the syntax `methodName _` to transform your method into a function :

  ```
  scala> def x = println("hello")
  x: Unit

  scala> x _
  res0: () => Unit = <function0>
  ```